# Maximum lua string-safe charset?

Tags: string, encoding, lua, compression, escaping

I'm currently working on a way to decompress lua scripts at runtime. I use luamin + lualzw + base85, which gives me 50% decrease in code size, however I was wondering how could I increase the efficiency. I ran a simple script which pointed out that the only forbidden single characters in a string are LF, CR, \ and ' (because I started the string with ', if I started with ", this would be the forbidden char instead). This would give... base252. However, there are combinations of strings, like -- is a comment. I'm asking if there are any other combinations which might be problematic, or maybe someone could give me a list of chars safe in a string?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `--` inside a string literal is not a comment.

Comment: Thanks, @EgorSkriptunoff, I didn't know that.